# MySQL concurrency Control

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a custom news editorial CMS with PHP, MySQL and CSS. Multiple users will use this application. So I would like to lock articles while someone else editing theme.

1. How do I lock articles while editing (using php)
2. Notify the other user that someone is editing this article

.....

```
$id=$_GET['id'];  
$query="SELECT * FROM storyproposal WHERE id={$id} FOR UPDATE";
$result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
$story = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

......
             
                 Initial Headline: 
                         ">

```
             <div class="form-group">
             <label for="possibleIssues" >Possible Issues the story touches Upon: <label>
            <textarea rows="8" cols="40" id="possibleIssues" name="possibleIssues" class="form-control"><?php echo $story['possibleIssues']; ?></textarea>
             </div>

             <div class="form-group">
             <label for="initialLead" >Initial Lead: <label>
            <textarea rows="8" cols="60" id="initialLead" name="initialLead" class="form-control"><?php echo $story['initialLead']; ?></textarea>
             </div>
```

.........

Comment: Read about pessimistic lock http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876323/optimistic-and-pessimistic-locks

Comment: possible duplicate of [multi-user application record locking - best method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668063/multi-user-application-record-locking-best-method)